# Show updated data from Local Storage Angular 7 [Resolve]

Tags: angular

I have a component named "edit-user" where the user can edit his name or surname. This data is load and refresh correctly in the Local Storage, and my service is work fine, because the new data is change in database.

The problem is in my header, because still showing the name before is updated. But, if I refresh the browser the name shows correctly.
The components used are, user service, the edit user component and the header. The problem is in the view of the header.

This is my service:
user.service.ts

```
update(users, idUsuario): Observable<any> {
    let json = JSON.stringify(users);
    let params = "json=" + json;
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    return this.http.put(this.url + 'user/update/' + idUsuario, params, { headers: headers });
}
```

The service is work fine.

I guess the problem is in my edit and header component.

edit-login.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { filter, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Router, ActivationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { UserService, SettingsService } from '../../servicios/servicio.index';
import { users } from '../../model/users';
import { global } from '../../servicios/global'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-login',
  templateUrl: './edit-login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-login.component.css'],
  providers: [UserService, SettingsService]
})

export class EditLoginComponent implements OnInit {

  public titulo: string;
  public user: users;
  public status: string;
  public idUsuario;
  public identity;
  public url;

constructor(private userService: UserService, private router: Router, private title: Title,
    public _ajustes: SettingsService) {
    this.identity = this.userService.getIdentity();
    this.user = new users('', '', '', '', '', this.identity.perfil_idPerfil, 1, '', this.idUsuario);
    this.url = global.url;
    this.getIdUsuario();
    this.user = new users(this.identity.nombreUsuario, this.identity.apellidoUsuario, this.identity.email,
      this.identity.password, this.identity.avatar, this.identity.perfil_idPerfil, 1, 'tema', this.idUsuario);
  }

 ngOnInit() {
    this.colocarCheck();
    this.getIdUsuario();
  }
//In this function I call the service for update the data of the user
onSubmit(form) {
    this.userService.update(this.user, this.identity.sub).subscribe(
      response => {
        if (response.code == 200) {
          this.status = 'success';

          //update user
          if (response.changes.nombreUsuario) {
            this.user.nombreUsuario = response.changes.nombreUsuario;
          }
          if (response.changes.apellidoUsuario) {
            this.user.apellidoUsuario = response.changes.apellidoUsuario;
          }
          if (response.changes.avatar) {
            this.user.avatar = response.changes.avatar;
          }

          this.identity = this.user;
          localStorage.setItem('identity', JSON.stringify(this.identity));

          Swal.fire({
            type: 'success',
            title: 'Datos modificados correctamente'
          });

          this.router.navigate(['/inicio']);
        }
      },
      error => {
        this.status = 'error';
        console.log(<any>error);
        Swal.fire({
          type: 'error',
          title: 'Error al editar perfil'
        })
      });
  }
```

And finally I have my header component

header.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../../servicios/servicio.index';
import { global } from '../../servicios/global'
import { users } from 'src/app/model/users';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  public identity;
  public url;

  public idUsuario;

  public usuario: users;

  constructor( public userService: UserService ) { 
    this.identity = this.userService.getIdentity();
    this.url = global.url;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getIdUsuario();
  }

  getIdUsuario() {
    if (!this.identity.id)
      this.idUsuario = this.identity.sub;
    else
      this.idUsuario = this.identity.id;
  }
}
```

The **getIdentity** function get the information from the LocalStorage, and this function is in my user.service.ts

```
getIdentity() {
    let identity = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('identity'));
    if (identity && identity != 'undefined') {
      this.identity = identity;
    } else {
      this.identity = null;
    }
    return this.identity;
  }
```

And, in the HTML header component, I show the information like this.

```
<div class="u-text">
     <h4> {{ identity.nombreUsuario + ' ' + identity.apellidoUsuario }} </h4>
     <p class="text-muted"> {{ identity.email }} </p>
     <p class="text-muted"> {{tipoUsuario}} </p>
```

I've seen a lot of similar questions but it's not working for me. I've read that I need to use a ngDoCheck in my header component, but I don't know how to use it. I've tried to use a EventEmitter in the service and the other components, but it's not working either. In other component in the same project I've use a EventEmitter and works correctly. But I don't know how to implement in this case.

Comment: You can use a `Subject` to notify the `header` when the data changes in the `onSubmit` function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jacopo, I'll try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally is was very easy to resolve. I just need to use a "DoCheck" in the header component. Something like this:

**user.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, DoCheck } from '@angular/core';

constructor(public userService: UserService) {
    this.cargarUsuario();
    this.url = global.url;
  }

ngDoCheck(){
    this.cargarUsuario();
  }

  cargarUsuario(){
    this.identity = this.userService.getIdentity();
  }
```

Comment: That can work but it's far from an ideal solution. You should really try to understand the component interaction in Angular.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `BehaviorSubject` in your **UserService** to emit the changes to all subscribers:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  identity = new BehaviorSubject('');

  constructor() {
    // get the identity from localStorage
    this.identity.next('initial_value');
  }

  updateIdentity(newIdentity: string) {
    this.identity.next(newIdentity);
    // also set the identity in localStorage;
  }
}
```

And in you **HeaderComponent** you subsribe to the `BehaviorSubject`:

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  public identity;

  constructor( public userService: UserService ) {   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.identity.subscribe(res => {
      this.identity = res;
    });
  }
}
```

Check this Stackblitz I made: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dn3waf

That's one way to do it. For more info you can check the Angular documentation about [Component Interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction).

Comment: Thanks kari for your answer. I'll try it inmeadiately and see what's happend

Comment: I've tried to implement your solution. But the name in the header still not changing. I checked twice, and I still think the problem is the ngOnInit from the header, because the BehaviorSubject doesn't show my console.log, it's like  the header component doesn't enter into the functions. I'm still looking for other options to resolve that problem.

Comment: It would be nice to see your code. If you are talking about `ngOnInit` of your HeaderComponent then you should call `this.userService.updateIndentity(newIdentity)` so that BehaviorSubject can emit the new value.

Comment: I will try again with that change in the ngOnInit and see other details. Thanks for your time !

Comment: Better use a `Subject` since the code doesn't access the value directly.

Comment: `Subject` doesn't hold a value but `BehaviorSubject` does. I feel it's easier to set the initial value (or last value) with `BehaviorSubject` because it will stay available for new subscribers without any additional code.

Comment: I think the BehaviorSubject should emitt a signal from the edit component. Because how header component know that the localstorage has change? I can't still understand the logic or the order for the BehaviorSubject.

Comment: The `BehaviorSubject` should be placed in a shared component. That way it can emit the new values to all other components that subscribe to it. You call the `updateIdentity(newIdentity: string)` of the UserService from, for example, the EditComponent and that way all other components will be notified when the identity changes. You should also centralize all localStorage related methods in the UserComponent as I showed in the Stackblitz example.